# Construction of the Reals in ZFC system: Existence of rational sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I am constructing the reals according to my Set Theory notes, and the approach we take is through rational Cauchy sequences.

My question is: how do we know that we even have sequences in our system, i.e. how do we show their existence via the axioms?

Thanks

Comment: Sequences are functions $\mathbb N\to \mathbb Q.$ Hasn't your class shown how to define functions between two sets (and even shown that there is a set $\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}$ consisting of exactly these functions)?

Comment: Yes I am aware of this fact. I just didn't make the connection. In my head I was thinking: "How can we have an infinite list of elements of rationals...?". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: $\Bbb N$ - ✓

Step 2: $\Bbb Z$ - ✓

Step 3: $\Bbb Q$ - ✓

Step 4: Definition of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb Q$ - ✓

Step 5: Definition of a function - ✓

Step 6: Definition of a sequence (special function) - ✓

Step 7: Existence of null sequence $(0,0,\dots)$ - ✓

Step 8: Existence of power set $\mathcal P$ operator - ✓

Step 9: Collection of all sequences of rational numbers is a subset $\mathcal P(\Bbb N \times \Bbb Q)$ - ✓

---

Note: Step 7 was not necessary, but was added for pedagogical reasons.